# I cannot retrieve my groups using Facebook SDK 5.1 using C#

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, facebook-group

I am using the Facebook SDK and I am trying with C# to get the groups the user is subscribed to. The code is as follows

```
JsonObject Groups = (JsonObject)client.Get("me/groups");
```

After this code executes I get an empty object. Is it something that I am missing?

The sale code for likes (`JsonObject Groups = (JsonObject)client.Get("me/likes");`)  and friends (`JsonObject Groups = (JsonObject)client.Get("me/friends");`) is working ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prompt the user for user_groups  extended permission.

Comment: Can you please explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

As I was having the same issue and couldn't find help anywhere, I thought I'd necro this with an explanation on how to solve the problem, as requested by @DustyRoberts.

If you get an empty object when requesting `me/groups` or `{user-id}/groups` it's because you're lacking the `user_managed_groups` permission (was `user_groups` prior to Graph API version 2.3).

You can do this by adding the `scope` parameter when logging in the user. It's a comma seperated list of permissions. You can see a full list of permissions [here (v2.4)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference).

```
    public static Uri GetLoginUrl(bool rerequestPermissions)
    {
        var client = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic para = new ExpandoObject();
        para.client_id = Settings.AppId;
        para.redirect_uri = Settings.LoginRedirUrl;
        para.response_type = Settings.ResponseType;
        para.scope = Settings.Scope; // Includes user_managed_groups

        // true if you've detected that one or more permissions have been denied
        // or revoked. It'll promt the user to grant the permissions again as when they
        // first used your app.
        if (rerequestPermissions)
            para.auth_type = "rerequest";

        return client.GetLoginUrl(para);
    }
```

More on checking for permissions [here (v2.4)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#checking)

I hope this helps someone cause it's exactly the information I needed to make it work.

Comment: what will be the http://graph.facebook ......... link for getting my all joined groups.

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman it's detailed in the question, actually. You just need to `Get("me/groups")` and you'll have them, provided you have the permission to do so as per my answer. Otherwise I have misunderstood your question, I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks for the respond, You r right, I will get the groups like this, but these are the groups which created by Me, and I need the groups which I have joined ... i.e. almost 100 groups I have joined, some are Closed Groups and some are Public Groups, so I need to get the List of all my Joined Groups. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that does pose a real problem. The method to do that has been deprecated in the Graph API. You will only be able to retrieve groups that, as you say yourself, have created or, I think, are admin in. I have difficulty seeing why Facebook made that decision.. I had the same problem as you and it was VERY frustrating. I ended up doing something nasty and reading the HTML and clicking links.. *shudders* but I needed to automate some image cleanup in massive albums. That's another thing, Graph API cannot delete things you (or perhaps even it) didn't create.

Comment: Oh! sad to hear the deprecation of such functionality. It means, we have to do manually something with such large list of groups. But anyway, thanks for the info. :)